# stdin stdout copy/paste doesn't work

Tags: vim, stdout, stdin

I using bash to search files on my PC))

so, I type

```
ls | vim -
```

It's working. 
But I want to copy string from vim and paste it to bash back. And it doesn't work.
From saved file I can copy/paste using

```
"*Y
```

but, if file is unsave it not working.

Comment: how do you copy after you yanked to `*` register? have you tried with mouse middle click?

Comment: middle click doesn't work

Comment: what is the output of `set mouse?`

Comment: set mouse=a

When I added set clipboard=unnamed in vimrc, yank worked great

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply yank a selected text (`y` key) and then in terminal paste it with `Shift+Insert`; you'll need this setting in `~/.vimrc` to make yank use clipboard:

```
set clipboard=unnamed  " use clipboard reg '*' for all yank & like operations
```

Works for both vim & gvim.